# Is there a way to record music with a collaborator remotely and live?

Tags: composition, recording, composers, pop-music, rock-n-roll

Is there a way to record music with a collaborator remotely and live? Appreciate the help!

Comment: Cubase VST Connect - https://www.steinberg.net/en/products/vst/vst_connect/vst_connect_pro.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  Here's one method 'VST Connect':

https://www.steinberg.net/en/products/vst/vst_connect/vst_connect_pro.html

Here's a more general discussion of the concept.

https://www.soundonsound.com/techniques/remote-collaboration

Comment: VST Connect only works with Cubase and Nuendo, no?