# is there any way to share high-quality protools mix audio and do two-way communication online?

Tags: daw, protools

I recorded a song using ProTools. I would like to work closely in real time with my very talented mix engineer as he mixes it remotely from his studio. Is there any way to do a zoom (or facetime) situation where i can hear **high quality audio** as the engineer works?
EDIT: 44.1khz/16-bit uncompressed OR 192kbps MP3 would be entirely adequate.

I.e., when he presses play, the music plays for me also. As he adjusts effects, I hear those instantly (100-200 millseconds latency is fine).

We also need to be able to converse freely to discuss the progress of his mix. I need to be able to interrupt him and ask for changes. We need to be able to ask each other questions and give answers.
EDIT: please no suggestions of 'just let him do his work.' The whole point of this question is that I want to closely supervise the mix process.

I have seen this question asked here in [other](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/86337/is-there-a-way-to-record-music-with-a-collaborator-remotely-and-live) [threads](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/87314/is-there-any-way-to-work-simultaneously-on-the-same-daw-project-remotely) but those questions are slightly different and the answers suggested in those other threads recommend tools like Steinberg's VST Transit, VST Connect, bandlab, etc which don't work for this particular application for various reasons:

- VST connect is cubase/nuendo only
- VST transit is really just a sort of file sync app and doesn't satisfy my needs for close, real-time collaboration.

Some complicating factors:

- The protools project is complex. It has several dozen tracks of drums, guitars, bass, explosions, tons of stuff.
- We have entirely different operating systems (he's got OSX, I have Ubuntu)

Seems to me that we might accomplish this most easily by using some existing video chat program like zoom or facetime or skype, but It's very very important that I'm able to hear very high quality audio of the mix as he works on it and I'm concerned about the possible compression settings that might come into play and also want to be sure that the two-way communication doesn't cause interrupts or otherwise interfere with his DAW.

Any suggestions would be most welcome.

Comment: Do you want your engineer to engineer the song, or be a remote pair of your hands? Just give him the tracks, give him a brief, and then leave him alone to do his magic.

Comment: I hope you have a very good internet connection... Raw audio can be heavy.

Comment: @Tom_C is right.  CD quality audio is 1.4MBPS (https://homedjstudio.com/audio-bitrates-formats/) uncompressed.  You can use compressed audio streams like .mp3, but then you add latency which is also a significant problem with real-time collaboration.  In the IT world, there's a saying, "You can have fast, good or cheap.  Pick two of the three."

Comment: Generally, screen sharing utilities and VoIP software use codecs that are optimized for human speech, not for music (because, well, that is what they are most commonly used for). So I doubt you'd get optimal results that way.

Comment: @PeteCon I'm the recording engineer and producer, he's the mix engineer, and I pay him. He does have a certain amount of magic, but it's totally inadequate to 'let him do his magic.' The mix is a cooperative effort which requires close interaction.

Comment: @Duston you raise a good point but yes my internet can easily handle 1.4Mbits/sec.

Comment: @Taschi yes I'm concerned about the codec in use. MP3 quality (even 128 kbps) would be adequate. 192 kbps far better. I guess I'm wondering what sort of audio mixing/routing might be possible and do zoom or face time (or some other chat program??) offer additinal settings?

Comment: Maybe something like YouTube live would be the solution for you to get a better audio quality than chat programs. However you would not be able to interact, maybe just adding a phone would be fine..

Comment: @Tom I've been casually looking into solutions for this and have nothing definitive, but  your YouTube live suggestion seems like a pretty good one. Youtube has a sort of [introductory video for encoders](https://youtu.be/DgeZxkHwSTo). As you point out, this lacks two-way comms but a FaceTime or phone call would be fine. I understand that with Zoom you can share your computer's audio, but haven't yet tried it.